# How to reduce the memory footprint in Loadrunner scripts

Tags: scripting, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using loadrunner tool for the performance testing. In the scripts I am using functions like lr_save_string , lr_parammarr_random ... Usage of these functions will increase the memory footprint.

So what will be the solution for this problem ? Please share your ideas here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your level of experience with LoadRunner, nor which language/protocol you are using.  But there are some general rules of thumb here

- Lightest weight users are C virtual users. So, if you are using a JavaScript or a Java virtual user where a C virtual user is an option, you can reduce the overall system footprint per virtual user
- New users often over-allocate the buffer size for correlations and don't reuse variables.  This can explode the memory size of a virtual user, especially if you combine this with no variable re-use.  The difference can be astounding, running from a couple of MB up to hundreds of MB for the same virtual user in C.
- Yes, when you create a new variable, using tools such as lr_save_string(), lr_parammarr_random(), ....  some amount of memory has to be allocated to hold that information.  Youc an certainly use language specific memory variables, taking the information from the LR data and saving it to a language specific memory variable of a defined size (or on the fly using malloc() with C).  The loadrunner funtions are there to speed development, but you don't have to use them.   But, be careful, make sure you clean up after yourself on the variable creation of you could wind up with leaky code on your generators.   It happens...
- Most of the time when these questions come up it is because the tester is trying to get the maximum possible on a single load generator, such as 5000 virtual users on machine X.   Consider that your test bed can also introduce issues, such as an overloaded generator will manifest as slow response times even if the application is fast.   I try to leave 50% of the available resource pool on the generators I use, plus a control generator (HW/VM matched) which only includes a single virtual user of each type.   If the control group and the global group degrade at the same rate, confidence is high that this is a common source issue - the app.   If, on the other hand, the control group and the global group degrade at different rates, i.e., the global group on maxed out load generators is slow but the control group is fast, then you have a test definition skewed response time.